# mysql log files are empty although it seems that I have set eveything

Tags: mysql, logging

I am trying to get log files for mysql server `Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.5.22` running on debian-linux-gnu (x86_64) using readline 6.2

Based on several websites I uncommented these lines in `/etc/mysql/my.cnf`:

```
general_log_file        = /var/log/mysql/mysql.log 
general_log             = 1
```

After running mysql I checked that `/var/log/mysql/mysql.log` was not created.
A website suggested to run two commands:

```
touch /var/log/mysql/mysql.log
chown mysql:mysql /var/log/mysql/mysql.log
```

This did not help: still no logs! The file is empty.

Answer (score 12):

Did you restart the server after updating the `my.cnf` file?

Please issue:

```
SELECT @@global.general_log;
SELECT @@global.general_log_file;
SELECT @@global.log_output;
```

These are the de-facto variables as the server sees them.
You may change tgem dynamically as follows:

```
SET GLOBAL general_log:=1;
SET GLOBAL log_output := 'FILE';
```

Also, as last resort, try:

```
FLUSH LOGS;
```

to close+reopen log file descriptor.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue with MySQL 5.5 at Ubuntu 14.04. Permisions and configurations were OK, but FLUSH LOGS returned

```
ERROR 1105 (HY000): Unknown error
```

Turned out, the issue was caused by incorrect AppArmor setup.

If this is the case the /var/log/syslog file contains lines like

```
<from kernel>: apparmor="DENIED" operation="mknod" profile="/usr/sbin/mysqld" name="/var/log/mysql/mysql.log" pid=16798 comm="mysqld" requested_mask="c" denied_mask="c" fsuid=115 ouid=115
```

Fix the AppArmor configuration in file /etc/apparmor.d/usr.sbin.mysqld and then restart AppArmor and MySQL.